# How to deal with airflow error taskinstance.py line 983, in _run_raw_task / psycopg2?

Tags: airflow, psycopg2

I have a couple of DAGs running, which execute python scripts which are basically copying data from A to B. But one of the dags throws an error - but data is still getting copied, so somehow it does not have influence on the execution of the python script.

The only "special" what is within this dag is, that the python script builds up a connecton to a postgres database using psycopg2~=2.8.5 but not sure if this is somehow the root cause.

I also checked the permissions for the user, which seem to be fine at least in the dags folder.

Is there any specific timeout value I have to adjust in the config?

```py
[2021-05-19 12:53:42,036] {taskinstance.py:1145} ERROR - Bash command failed 255
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/hereisthepath/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 983, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/hereisthepath/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 134, in execute
    raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed
```

Update: This is the passage of the operator, which fails. I copied the entire function, however the error throws at line 134 ("raise AirflowException("Bash command failed"))

```py
    def execute(self, context):
        """
        Execute the bash command in a temporary directory
        which will be cleaned afterwards
        """
        self.log.info("Tmp dir root location: \n %s", gettempdir())

        # Prepare env for child process.
        env = self.env
        if env is None:
            env = os.environ.copy()
        airflow_context_vars = context_to_airflow_vars(context, in_env_var_format=True)
        self.log.debug('Exporting the following env vars:\n%s',
                       '\n'.join(["{}={}".format(k, v)
                                  for k, v in airflow_context_vars.items()]))
        env.update(airflow_context_vars)

        self.lineage_data = self.bash_command

        with TemporaryDirectory(prefix='airflowtmp') as tmp_dir:
            with NamedTemporaryFile(dir=tmp_dir, prefix=self.task_id) as f:

                f.write(bytes(self.bash_command, 'utf_8'))
                f.flush()
                fname = f.name
                script_location = os.path.abspath(fname)
                self.log.info(
                    "Temporary script location: %s",
                    script_location
                )

                def pre_exec():
                    # Restore default signal disposition and invoke setsid
                    for sig in ('SIGPIPE', 'SIGXFZ', 'SIGXFSZ'):
                        if hasattr(signal, sig):
                            signal.signal(getattr(signal, sig), signal.SIG_DFL)
                    os.setsid()
                self.log.info("Running command: %s", self.bash_command)
                self.sub_process = Popen(
                    ['bash', fname],
                    stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
                    cwd=tmp_dir, env=env,
                    preexec_fn=pre_exec)

                self.log.info("Output:")
                line = ''
                for line in iter(self.sub_process.stdout.readline, b''):
                    line = line.decode(self.output_encoding).rstrip()
                    self.log.info(line)
                self.sub_process.wait()
                self.log.info(
                    "Command exited with return code %s",
                    self.sub_process.returncode
                )

                if self.sub_process.returncode:
                    raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")

        if self.xcom_push_flag:
            return line
```

Update2: It really seems, that this behavior is related to the psycopg2: I now tested all other possible error sources and only when I test with the postgres datasource using psycopg2 package, the error occurs. Meanwhile I also upgraded to the most recent version of psycopg2 (2.8.6) but without success.

Maybe this helps for further investigation

Comment: Please provide the code related to the `Operator` that raises this exception or even the code related to the complete DAG.

Comment: Hi @NicoE, thx for your reply. I editet my original post accordingly and copied the entire function. It seems, that some kind of temporary directory is getting created which somehow fails. But still I am wondering, why it is working for all other DAGs. I guess, that all DAGs use the same function.